# Failed to connect to Postgres database Postgres requires connecting to a specific database, the following databases were tried:

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm getting this error when i try to connect my fabric-ca to use postgres as a database.

```
Using postgres database, connecting to database...
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [DEBUG] Database Name: fabriccaserver
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [DEBUG] Connecting to PostgreSQL server, using connection string: host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=**** password=**** dbname=fabriccaserver sslmode=disable
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [WARNING] Failed to connect to database 'fabriccaserver'
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [DEBUG] Connecting to PostgreSQL server, using connection string: host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=**** password=**** dbname=postgres sslmode=disable
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [WARNING] Failed to connect to database 'postgres'
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [DEBUG] Connecting to PostgreSQL server, using connection string: host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=**** password=**** dbname=template1 sslmode=disable
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [WARNING] Failed to connect to database 'template1'
    2019/10/22 09:21:16 [ERROR] Error occurred initializing database: Failed to connect to Postgres database. Postgres requires connecting to a specific database, the following databases were tried: [fabriccaserver postgres template1]. Please create one of these database before continuing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this error by putting container_name in the host  i,e.

```
db:
  db:
  type: postgres
  datasource: host=db-postgres port=5432 user=postgres password=caDbPass12345 dbname=fabriccaserver sslmode=disable  
  tls:
      enabled: false
      certfiles:
      client:
        certfile:
        keyfile:
```

Previously, i was entering localhost and also tried with 127.0.0.1 and after that i saw that in my docker-compose.yaml my postgres service was under different network and ica.org1.example.com was under different network which i fixed and also had to do docker network prune after killing and removing all the docker processes.